# Webpack / Yarn Error after Renaming Rails 6.1 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I had a previously-functional app on Rails 6.1 that had successfully deployed to Heroku.

I (unfortunately) had to rename the app, which I did following [these](https://dev.to/morinoko/rename-a-rails-app-including-database-github-and-heroku-names-3lch) steps.

- The app (post renaming) works perfectly on localhost.
- I am 100% sure my code-to-Github relationship is working, because new commits show up on Github.
- I have since deleted all git remotes as well as the Heroku app.  I recreated a Heroku app and set it as a production remote.

I still get the following error every time I try to push to heroku:

```
remote:        Compiling...
remote:        Compilation failed:
remote:        yarn run v1.22.4
remote:        info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        error Command "webpack" not found.
remote:        
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to the-failure-project.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/the-failure-project.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/the-failure-project.git'
```

I tried adding buildpacks, as recommended [here](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/512):

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
heroku buildpacks:add --index 2 heroku/ruby
```

I'm stumped.  Please help!